# Why does disabling arrow keys in Insert mode (e.g. `inoremap <left> <nop>`) result in e.g. `0D` being written?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I want to disable the arrow keys in Insert mode, since I want to force myself to always go into Normal mode for performing movements.

To achive this, I've made the following mappings for Insert mode, which should (AFAIK) make the arrow keys have no effect (NOP).

However, pressing e.g. `<left>` in Insert mode results in `0D` being written in the buffer, which is **not** want I want.

How can I disable the arrow keys without "side-effects"?

```
" Disable arrow keys (Insert mode)
inoremap <left> <nop>
inoremap <down> <nop>
inoremap <up> <nop>
inoremap <right> <nop>
```

[image]

Comment: If you use a `.vimrc` with only those 4 statements and invoke `vim --noplugin`, does the problem still happen?

Comment: Thank you. Using `vim -u /dev/null --noplugin` makes the arrow keys result in `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

Comment: Arrow keys send special codes in a terminal that start with escape (in my terminal, that would be Escape followed by OA, OB, OC, and OD). Remapping escape tends to break things; it’s possible this is related.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I'm not sure what you mean. ` vim -u /dev/null --noplugin` makes it certain that I load no `~/.vimrc` file and that no plugins in `./vimrc/pack` is loaded right (please confirm)? Then why do arrow keys result in those codes? I manually execute `:inoremap <left> <nop>` in Ex mode, and verify the result using `:inoremap`.

Comment: @Shuzheng wasn't clear after `vim -u /dev/null ...` that you manually did `:inoremap`, I'll edit my comments. With that version, the arrow keys probably trigger `<esc>OA`, which inserts a letter in the buffer (because of `O`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I fixed the problem! When executing `vim -u /dev/null ...`, the default was `:set compatible`, so arrow keys resulted in `A`, `B`, ... Here `:set nocompatible` fixed the problem. When executing `vim` using my custom `~/.vimrc` including `:inoremap <esc> <nop>`, the arrow keys resulted in `0A`, `0B`, ... Here `:iunmap <esc>` fixed the problem. Why does mapping `<esc>` in Insert mode break things? I want to force myself not leaving Insert mode using `^[`.

Comment: Do *not* remap escape. It breaks things because it breaks how vim handles special codes (such as those used the terminal for drawing, handling arrow keys, etc.)

Comment: We had another question going into detail of the problems with `imap <esc> <nop>`, particularly regarding arrow keys, so I marked this one as a duplicate.